# Changing display name of an Android app by modifying its apk file - (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to change the display name of an Android file (the name shown on the screen once the app is installed). I only have the apk file*.

When I unzip the apk file, it's partially binarized. I know that to change the display name, I have to change the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but that file is partially in binary.

If I unzip an application, change something (or nothing!), zip it back up, sign and zipalign it, the application does not work anymore. It doesn't install, but crashes while trying, claiming `Parse Error - There was a problem while parsing the package.`

If I unzip the application using [ApkTool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/%20ApkTool), change something (or nothing) and rezip it using the `apktool b apkFolder -o changedApk.apk`, then sign and zipalign it, the app does install, my changes seem to be present, but the app crashes the moment it opens up. The stacktrace seems to indicate that the following is the problem:

```
F/monodroid(12679): No assemblies found in '(null)' or '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Geocortex.App/files/.__override__'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
```

If I rezip the application using the `apktool b apkFolder` (thus to place the changes in the original apk file), sign and zipalign, the application installs and works, but none of my changes are present. The last modified date on the apk actually doesn't even change, so it seems like the tool does nothing.

ApkTool seems to have been successfully used in the past by many others to do the same thing as me, but now I am wondering if perhaps it wasn't updated to the Android L version.

I also noticed that the original unchanged apk is about 3 mb bigger than the output from both the apktool and the regular rezip. As another side note, I am using the original key, keychain, password to resign the app.

Does anyone know how to do this, or why the application might be crashing? Does the apktool work for Android 5.0+? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

---

*Details about the source of the apk and my authorization (as requested by Chris in his comment): This particular application belongs to the company I work for (so yes, I do have the entire source code and could change the `AndroidManifest.xml` file there). However, this application is distributed to our limited clients manually. This application does not exist in the app store and every version is manually changed to suit a certain client's desires (e.g. specific app names or icons that match their company). In order to alleviate some of the developer's work load, I am creating a Windows Program that can do all these changes automatically and the work for our team would be as easy as having to type in a new name in a textbox. At the end of the project, I plan on having a Windows tool that can take the current version of our application (in its apk format), change the app name or display icons which were inputted in simple text fields, and output signed and zipaligned application that can be easily sent to our customers.

Comment: Please explain how you are *authorized* to do this, but lack the source.  And regardless of that, "my app crashed" type questions here require a stack trace of the crash.  For all we know, you've hit an anti-piracy check that is purposefully crashing the app because it has been signed with a substitute key.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Thank you for your comment! I have updated the question to reflect my authority. I would like to be able to get a stack trace of the crash, but I am not that familiar with Android Studio. Do you have any suggestions for me? (I'll make some Google searches too)

Comment: Your goal is most easily accomplished using build automation, something your development team should have in place anyway.

Comment: Instead of unzipping using apktool, decompile it. Find the strings.xml file and change the string that holds the app name. Then try to recompile. Also, you may need to update your aapt that apktool is using

Comment: Your stack trace is not meaningful.  Your developers may have put in exception handlers which give useless output (the default is many times more informative), in which case they will have to change/remove those first.

Comment: If you want to do changes in your project for specific users, why won't you just copy whole project and edit it, instead of playing with decompilation?